# How to set overlay panel extjs when page of web app end rendered

Tags: extjs, web-applications, overlay, extjs6

How to set overlay panel extjs when page of web app end rendered? Like info panel or login panel. I wish that info overlay panel rendered immediately after rendering of whole page. Which method the best?

Comment: I'd recommend to use modal windows very sparingly

Comment: Use afterrender listener,  listeners:{
             afterrender:function(){
                 //Call your window modal
             }   
            }

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [modal](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/classic/Ext.window.Window.html#cfg-modal) window in application's [launch method](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/classic/Ext.app.Application.html#method-launch).

Here is a working fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2pr7